# CherryPy XML-RPC-Server as Windows Service

Tags: python, xml-rpc, cherrypy, pywin32

I'm trying to start an CherryPy XML-RPC-Server as Windows Service in combination with pywin32. This works on windows 7 but not on windows xp.
The script runs fine in the debug mode (i. e. not as service) but as a service I get the following log output:

```
2015-08-14 16:55:18,187 INFO    BuildServerService  Start Service...
2015-08-14 16:55:18,187 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Bus STARTING
2015-08-14 16:55:18,187 ERROR   cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Set handler for console events.
2015-08-14 16:55:18,187 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 ERROR   cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Error in HTTP server: shutting down
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programme\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py", line 206, in _start_http_thread
self.httpserver.start()
File "C:\Programme\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver3.py", line 1648, in start
raise socket.error(msg)
OSError: No socket could be created -- (('0.0.0.0', 9000): [WinError 10106] Der angeforderte Dienstanbieter konnte nicht geladen oder initialisiert werden)
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 9000)) already shut down
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 ERROR   cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Removed handler for console events.
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Bus EXITING
2015-08-14 16:55:18,218 INFO    cherrypy.error  [14/Aug/2015:16:55:18] ENGINE Bus EXITED
2015-08-17 08:50:16,665 INFO    cherrypy.error  [17/Aug/2015:08:50:16] ENGINE Console event 0: shutting down bus
```

Interesting is the part **OSError: No socket could be created** but why exactly is that not possible in a service ?

My Implementation is as follow:

```
import builtins, os, win32event, win32serviceutil, win32service, servicemanager, socket, logging
from UseCases.ProductionEngineering.Development.Ctt.Deployment.BuildServer.BuildXMLRPCInterface import BuildXMLRPCInterface as Interface

class BuildServerService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    '''
    classdocs 
    '''
    _svc_name_ = "BuildServerService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Build Server Service"
    _WORKING_DIRECTORY = "C:\BuildServerService\Sources"
    _svc_deps_ = None  # sequence of service names on which this depends
    # Only exists on Windows 2000 or later, ignored on Windows NT
    _svc_description_ = "Build Server Service"
    def __init__(self, args, debug=False):
        self.debug = debug
        if not self.debug:
            builtins.RUNNING_AS_SERVICE = True
            # disable user interfaces in services because this causes errors during startup
            builtins.NO_UserInterface = True
            win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.hSockEvent = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(self._WORKING_DIRECTORY, "service.log"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(name)s\t%(message)s')
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.log(1, 'Load ' + __file__)
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import  os.path, cherrypy
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(path)

        self.logger.info("Start Service...")
        config = {
              'global' : {
                'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0',
                'server.socket_port' : 9000,
                'server.thread_pool' : 8,
                'log.screen': True,
                'engine.autoreload.on': False,
                'engine.SIGHUP': None,
                'engine.SIGTERM': None,

              },
              '/' : {
                'tools.xmlrpc.on': True,
                'tools.xmlrpc.allow_none' : True
              }
            }
        cherrypy.quickstart(Interface(), '/api', config)    

    def SvcStop(self):
        import  cherrypy
        # close server and call inherited class method
        self.logger.info("Stop Service...")
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        cherrypy.engine.exit()
        if self.debug:
            return
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                              (self._svc_name_, '. Bye'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #sc = BuildServerService(None, debug=True)
    #sc.SvcDoRun()
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(BuildServerService)
```

I use the winpython distribution with python 3.3.5 and the following modules:

```
CherryPy==3.8.0
Cython==0.20.1
Django==1.7
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.18
Pillow==2.4.0
Polygon==3.0.5
PyOpenGL==3.0.2
PyQtdesignerplugins==1.1
PyQtdoc==4.8.4
PySide==1.2.1
PyWavelets==0.3.0
Pygments==1.6
SQLAlchemy==0.9.4
Scidoc==1.8.0
SocksiPy-branch==1.02
Sphinx==1.2.2
TTFQuery==1.0.4
VPython==5.74
astroid==1.0.1
certifi==2015.04.28
chardet==2.3.0
colorama==0.2.7
comtypes==1.1.1
cx-Freeze==4.3.2
django-pyodbc-azure==1.2.1
docutils==0.11
docx==0.2.4
fonttools==2.3
formlayout==1.0.15
genicam==0.0.0-20150331112308-pylon-4.2.1.4845
guidata==1.6.1
guiqwt==2.3.2
h5py==2.2.1
ipython==2.0.0
logging==0.4.9.6
logilab-common==0.61.0
lxml==3.4.4
mahotas==1.1.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
mpld3==0.2
networkx==1.8.1
nose==1.3.1
numexpr==2.3.1
numpy==1.8.1
opencv3-python==3.0.0.dev0
pandas==0.13.1
patsy==0.2.1
psutil==2.1.0
pyhdf==0.8.3
pylint==1.1.0
pylon==0.0.0-20150331112313-pylon-4.2.1.4845
pyodbc==3.0.7
pyparsing==2.0.1
pyreadline==2.0
pyserial==2.7
python-dateutil==2.2
python-docx==0.8.5
pytz==2013.9
pywin32==218.5
pyzmq==14.0.1
regex==2015.06.24
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.5.0
scikit-image==0.9.3
scikit-learn==0.14.1
scipy==0.13.3
simplejson==3.3.3
six==1.6.1
spyder==2.3.0beta2
statsmodels==0.5.0
sympy==0.7.5
tables==3.1.1
tornado==4.2.1
vispy==0.2.1
wheel==0.24.0
winpython==1.0
xlrd==0.9.3
xml-diff==0.6.0
```

What do you think is that a pywin32 or a CherryPy issue ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is bind to all interfaces(loopback + * erhernet interface). But you got a unavailable interface and can't bind. Give a interface IP for bind(ex:192.168.1.10(what is your default interface ip ?))

Comment: This issue continues also with 'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0', 'server.socket_host' : '','server.socket_host' : 172.16.51.127', and 'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1'

Comment: 0.0.0.0 include ( '127.0.0.1', '172.16.51.127') already. if a service bind 0.0.0.0:9000 can't start any service on port 9000 !

Comment: bind only '172.16.51.127' and check which process are ghost ?

Comment: I'm totally agree with you but there are no other instance that binds to port 9000. I've just tried different configurations;)

Comment: is ghost friend. Close all idle orshell (reboot (recommended)) and try again, or put a condition in your thread. Dont serve directly. if use a "forever" need close, destroy not equal to close !

Comment: After some researches I can tell you that your ghost presumption isn't the reason for my problem.

Comment: As workaround I installed the service with [nssm](http://www.nssm.cc/download). I configured nssm that it starts my script as follow:                                                                                       sc = BuildServerService(None, debug=True)
sc.SvcDoRun() . Thus, the service no longer managed by pywin32 and works very well under windows xp